# "ELF built without Position Independent Executable (PIE) flag " for mips64 architecture but not for other architectures

Tags: android, shared-libraries, .so, fpic

I have generated a shared library .so file I did not use any flags  -fpic in CMakeLists.txt

But one of the tool reported "ELF built without Position Independent Executable (PIE) flag "  for mips64 architecture  but not for other architectures .

Anybody know how -fpic is taken care in other architectures  but not in mips64 ?
Do I need to use -fpic flag in CMakeLists.txt  file to build mips64

Answer (score 0):

Please update to latest ifix.

That should resolve your issue.